# Shortest solution to permute the elements of a std::vector using stl

Tags: c++, boost, stl, permutation, combinatorics

Assume that you have an `std::vector<T>` of some type `T` and a selection of indices `std::vector<int>` of this vector. Now I'm looking for a function `permute(const std::vector<T>& vector, const std::vector<int>& indices)`, that returns the permuted vector with respect to the given indices.

The problem is easily solved by writing a short function like depicted below:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> permute(const std::vector<T>& matrix, const std::vector<int>& indices) {
    std::vector<T> ret;
    for (auto p : indices) {
        ret.push_back(matrix[p]);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::vector<int> perm{ 1,2,0 };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = { {1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.},{7.,8.,9.} };
    auto matrixPerm=permute(matrix, perm);
    std::cout << matrixPerm[0][0] << " == " << matrix[1][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << matrixPerm[1][0] << " == " << matrix[2][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << matrixPerm[2][0] << " == " << matrix[0][0] << std::endl;
}
```

I'm now wondering what might be most elegant version of this program, if we can use STL or even the Boost libraries. In STL for example we have `shuffle()`, but we cannot say in what way to shuffle.

Does anyone now, how to shorten the function?

## Solution using `std::transform()`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::vector<int> perm{ 1,2,0 };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = { {1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.},{7.,8.,9.} };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> output;
    std::transform(perm.begin(), perm.end(), std::back_inserter(output), [&](int i) { return matrix[i]; });

    std::cout << output[0][0] << " == " << matrix[1][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << output[1][0] << " == " << matrix[2][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << output[2][0] << " == " << matrix[0][0] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The verb is "permute", not "permutate".

Comment: You could possibly use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) (version 3 of the overloads) instead of the explicit loop. But I don't know if it will really be "shorter" or more "elegant". What is you *actual* goal? What is the *real* problem you have?

Comment: My real problem is just to permute the elements of a vector. Of course the problem is simple, but I'm wondering why I still have to write so much. Shouldn't there a one-line solution?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Many thanks. I looked again at std::transform. It really does the job, but one has to iterate over perm and not over matrix. This point was not so clear to me beforehand.

Comment: While it works to do what you do, I would rather use another overload of `std::transform`, that allows *two* "input" containers. One would be your matrix, the other would be the index container.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Interesting. Why would you do so? Is there some advantage?

Comment: None other than it would be more self-contained.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Alright. I'll try your suggested solution.

Comment: You can avoid growing `output` with `std::vector<std::vector<double>> output(matrix.size()); std::transform(perm.begin(), perm.end(), output.begin(), [&](int i) { return matrix[i]; });`

Comment: @Caleth Good point. Even though I'm interested into shortness and not in a very fast solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the indices into iterators and then create an indirect range with Boost.Range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indirected.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    using namespace boost::adaptors;


    std::vector<int> perm{ 1,2,0 };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = { {1.,2.,3.},{4.,5.,6.},{7.,8.,9.} };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> output;
    auto permutation = perm | transformed( [&matrix](int x) { return matrix.begin() + x; }) | indirected;

    boost::copy(
        permutation,
        std::back_inserter(output));

    std::cout << output[0][0] << " == " << matrix[1][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << output[1][0] << " == " << matrix[2][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << output[2][0] << " == " << matrix[0][0] << std::endl;
}
```

You could skip copying the elements and just process the range if you don't need a real vector.

The range adaptor uses the permutation iterator from the Boost.Iterator library. You can also use this directly, but you have to manually define begin and end:

```
auto begin = make_permutation_iterator( matrix.begin(), perm.begin() );
auto end = make_permutation_iterator( matrix.end(), perm.end() );

std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(output) );
```

Comment: Works magically. I'll need some time to digest it. Even though it is a bit more lengthy, it seems to be applicable in more situations. Maybe I have to look a bit into `Boost-Range`.

Comment: @Aleph0 There is also Eric Niebler's range-v3 library (https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), which is the basis of the proposal for C++2x.